# Combine multiple outrigger tables into one?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have a dimensional table and several outriggers.

```
create table dimFoo (
    FooKey int primary key,
    ......
)

create table triggerA (
    FooKey int references dimFoo (FooKey),
    Value varchar(255),
    primary key nonclustered (FooKey, Value)
)

create table triggerB (
    FooKey int references dimFoo (FooKey),
    Value varchar(255)
    primary key nonclustered (FooKey, Value)
)

create table triggerC (
    FooKey int references dimFoo (FooKey),
    Value varchar(255)
    primary key nonclustered (FooKey, Value)
)
```

Should these outrigger tables be merged into one table?

```
create table Triggers (
    FooKey int references dimFoo (FooKey),
    TriggerType varchar(20), // triggerA, triggerB, triggerC, etc....
    Value varchar(255),
    primary key nonclustered (FooKey, TriggerType, Value)
)
```

Comment: I'd like to understand why they are outriggers. They look like text fields that are one-to-one with the dimension table itself (keyed on FooKey) so it sounds likely they should just be within the dimension table as columns.

Comment: There are many text items for each foo. It's a many to one relationship.

Comment: So if there was a PK on those tables it'd be on fookey + the value?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: It's starting to look more like a fact table, when combined.

Comment: No, a lot of dimensional tables have these cases. For example, in the dimCustomer, each customer may have multiple hobbies, sports, credit card numbers, phone numbers, favorite products, .... etc.

Comment: Yes, a kind of factless fact between dimensions. Some would call this an example of a bridge table rather than an outrigger- as mentioned here (hobbies mentioned as an example here too) http://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/05/design-tip-166-potential-bridge-table-detours/ . As to your question of combining, it'd probably depend how many you want and whether you want concretely named fields available for analysis, or whether you are happy for people to use the type column to know what their values mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146232/discussion-between-rich-and-dc7a9163d9).

Answer (score 0):

In order to meet this kind of scenario, such as with dimCustomer with customers potentially having multiple hobbies, the typical Kimball approach is to use a Bridge table between dimensions (dimCustomer and dimHobby).

[This link](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/05/design-tip-166-potential-bridge-table-detours/) provides a summary of how bridge tables could solve this problem and also alternatives which may work better for you.

Without knowing more about your specific scenario, including what the business requirements are, how many of these value types you have, how 'uniform' the various value types and values are, and the BI technology you'll be using for accessing the data, its hard to give a definitive answer to whether you should combine the bridges into one uber-bridge that caters for the various many-to-manys. All the above influence the answer to some extent.

Typically the 'generic tables' approach is more useful behind the scenes for administration than it is for presenting for analytics. My default approach would be to have specific bridge tables until/unless this became unmanageable from an ETL perspective or perceived as much more complex from a user query perspective. I wouldn't look to 'optimise' to a combined table from the get-go.

If your situation is outside the usual norms (do you have three as per your example, or ten?), combining could well be a good idea. This would make it more like a factless fact, with dimensions of dimCustomer, dimValueType and dimValue, and would be a perfectly reasonable solution.

Comment: In my case, the hobby is just a text string and I would like not create a dimension dimHobby for it. Etl will be used to make sure the values of hobby are valid.

Comment: As to whether you 'should' combine them, sure, if it helps you manage it better or make it easier to understand. If not, don't :-)